# Correct way to pass query parameter in C# as argument to IN operator in BigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I am looking to pass an array of strings as a query parameter to an `IN` operator. I have been struggling with this for a while now and nothing I try seems to work. I am wondering whether this is even possible to do.

I have tried the following syntax variants:

```
where state IN (@states)
where state IN @states
where state IN ARRAY(@states)
where state IN (ARRAY(@states))
```

And this is the C# end:

```
new BigQueryParameter("states", BigQueryDbType.Array, new[] {"AL", "CA"}),
new BigQueryParameter("states", null, new[] {"AL", "CA"}),
```

I get a variety of errors, depending on what I try:

- No matching signature for operator IN for argument types STRING and {ARRAY< STRING>}
- Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got "@"
- Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got keyword ARRAY
- Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got "@"

Comment: So, did you look up `UNNEST`? Does it not look like exactly what you *do* want here?

Comment: Didn't occur to me. I figured doing just `IN (@states)` had to work. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#from-clause) operator like so:

SQL

```
where state IN UNNEST(@states)
```

C#

```
new BigQueryParameter("states", BigQueryDbType.Array, new[] {"AL", "CA"}) {ArrayElementType = BigQueryDbType.String},
```

Comment: That does it. There is one more thing I discovered. In case one wants empty array to match ALL, the correct syntax seems to be `ARRAY_LENGTH(@states) IS NULL OR state IN UNNEST(@states)` rather than `ARRAY_LENGTH(@states) = 0 OR state IN UNNEST(@states)`. Seems strange but that's what worked for me.